# System.getenv doesn't pick any system variable on Amazon Linux

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I have instance host in Amazon EC2. I have set the environment variables in `/etc/profile` and exported them. Also I have put them on `/etc/environment`. `JAVA_HOME` is also included on both files.

I run my web service with the Wildfly 8.2 edition. the Wildfly install as a service. Unfortunately Any of my environment variable didn't pick when I call it; At lease the  `System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")` nor working. It returns `null`; Why is that happened? what is the solutions?

Comment: You need to add the system variables to a profile which is added on start up. Try seeing what your system properties are on the command line before you start Wildfly.

Comment: How do i do it?

Comment: Do you have shell access to the instance? If so run `echo $JAVA_HOME` and if it's blank, you haven't set JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

presumable you have installed the "Wildfly" service with systemd using a file like this

```
[Unit]
Description=WildFly application server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=wildfly
Group=wildfly
ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To set environment variables, add them to the "[Service]" section like this

```
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/myjava/1.8.0-102
```